# Hibernate Search - Natural Language Search

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I would like to know if we can use Hibernate search to do a full text search on a given term and return results analyzing on specific amount values.

i.e  The terms could be "show me all the transactions below 100" AND "show me all transactions from yesterday"

Any direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Search itself doesn't offer such feature. You may be able to use some natural language query processor that would create Lucene queries, though.

But given your query examples, I'm not sure full-text search is what you're looking for. When we say Hibernate Search is about "full-text" search, we mean it allows finely tuned queries in a great volume of text documents (books, for instance). "full-text" search has nothing to do with natural language analysis.